# There is some driver for a Epson AcuLaser c1700 printer enable for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: drivers

I moving to Ubuntu, and I like to install a printer, automatically when I connect the USB of my printer to my computer, this detect it, but the printer doesn't print because it doesn't installed a driver. I searched for Internet, but I don't found any driver for linux, but yes for Mac.

In the printer configuration, I found a driver. The driver Epson Aculaser C1700 Foomatic/foo2hbpl1

[image: Intall of the driver Epson Aculaser C1700 Foomatic/foo2hbpl1]

Also I installed in the ubuntu software the Synaptic package manager and with this program I installed the printer-driver-escpr
[image: printer-driver-escpr]

But, still the printer doesn't print.
The printer's status is the follow:
[image]
Thanks you.

I has checked the error log of cups and when I want to print any something. In the error log print follow it:

[image: 1/6]

[image: 2/6]

[image: 3/6]

[image: 4/6]

[image: 5/6]

[image: 6/6]

Also, when I want to print something, I get two notifications, one that It report me the printting (but, it doesn't print) and the other that it report me a error.

[image]

The printting is stopped for something.

How to I can to solution it?

Comment: "filter error"  means the settings are wrong (probably an invalid option). cups uses `/var/log/cups/error_log` as a log. Can you check if there is a notification that shows what the option is?

Comment: Some Time ago a read an articel that there is no Linux driver for this printer, but it is compatible with the printer Xerox Phaser 6000B. Check driver page https://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/file-download/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=116065&from=downloads&viewArchived=false

Comment: Thanks, thanks very much. The printer now print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the compatible printer driver of Xerox Phaser 6000B. The driver can be downloaded from https://www.support.xerox.com/support/phaser-6000/file-download/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB&contentId=116065&from=downloads&viewArchived=false

Comment: There is a driver Xerox Phaser 6000B for amd64 processors?